# How to permanently save a button click (iOS)

Tags: ios, button, uiimage, save, boolean

```
 -(IBAction)REDbutton:(id)sender{

item.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"REDthing.png"];

RED=YES;  //BOOL

if (RED==YES){    
    Red.hidden=NO;
    Purple=NO;   //BOOL
    Gold=NO;     //BOOL

}
```

The Above code is a button action. It says when the user clicks on REDbutton then the image becomes REDthing.png.

However, with the above code, after each GameOver, you have to click on the REDbutton. I want to make it that once the user clicks on the REDbutton, they never have to click it again. How do I make it save the user's REDbutton click?

For BOOL:

```
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"save"];
  RED= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"save"];
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

Comment: you need to show more code. Where do you set userDefaults? Where do you read userDefaults? etc...

Answer (score 0):

*The sure shot solution is to use a* `plist` *file to store the details but easiest solution is saving value in `NSUserDefault`.*

Comment: I tried NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults for the BOOL but it doesn't work.  How do I make a plist file?

Comment: Just gave you the concept, rest you can find it by little Googling.

Comment: I edited in the NSUserDefaults StandardUserDefaults for BOOL that I used. Maybe it's wrong. Is there a NSUserDefaults StandardUserDefaults for a button click?

Comment: Updated the answer for your help.

Comment: Why are you saving a `BOOL` in `NSUserDefaults` as an `NSString`? `NSUserDefaults` has methods for saving/loading an actual `BOOL` value.

Comment: When I get to the setBOOL: part of the code only the NSString pops up.